# 2 times the same project in the Class View Window (visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications

After converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio, it seems that there is a problem with some meta data. The first noticeable is the fact that the project is mentioned twice in the Class View window.

[image]

If I add a new namespace and a new class in it, I'm not able to select it using intellisense. when I open the hierarchy of the Class view, I see my new namespace in one of them (that are indentical except the recent addings)

Is there a way to clean that up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get rid off the App Folder. That's the origin of this problem.

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.be/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html